# Know whether two boundaries ever intersect each other in GEOKIT

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, geocoding, geokit, google-geocoding-api

I using Geokit Library for Geo Coding  Now the problem is that I have

**User Model** and **Event Model** each one has a **there radius** now I want all list of users whose boundaries actually intersect in Event boundaries

Here the scenario

```
  Like Event E1 has radius 20 (which look for all users in radius of 20 from event origin)  

  and 

  User A has radius 100 (which look for all events in radius of 100 from 'A' origin)  

  User B has radius 200 (which look for all events in radius of 200 from 'B' origin)

  User C has radius 10 (which look for all events in radius of 10 from 'C' origin)
```

Now all I  want is list of all User who can serve the event E1 keep in mind the **event radius**

I now there a method in geokit to find a point in bounds(**in_bounds**) But that not suffice my need cuz there could be scenario where the event(E1 origin) is out of bound of users but considering the event radius(E1 boundaries) it is in bound of that user

What I want is to know whether is there a way to determine whether a given two boundary intersect each others.

I hope I manage to make my point without actually confusion it

Consider It a case of intersection of two physical geographical boundary in geo-location and all I want is to know that given a set of boundaries whether they actually intersect or not

Regards

Comment: Ok there is one way to do to find this is to iterate over users and add there radius with event radius and Check whether event fall within the combine radius but this is an expensive task as can anyone suggest better

Answer (score 1):

i think there must be some method of it like there is in Google Maps library such as `contains()` or `intersects()` to check the bounds.

Comment: where did you find it It not mention any where in google geocoding api did you happen to find a page which I missed by chance